# Can I upload 100GB of images to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a lot of small images I want to host on Firebase Hosting.

I do not want to use Google CDN as the load balancer rules are expensive.

A public GCP bucket also seems much slower than the Firebase Hosting CDN.

Is such a large amount of files ok to upload?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you're willing to pay for it.  You might want to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/usage-quotas-pricing).  There is nothing stated about limits for a deployment.  You should be aware of one specific limit:

> Note that Hosting has a maximum size limit of 2 GB for individual files.

If you have a specific problem that isn't covered in the linked documentation, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.

Comment: Am I missing anything? 0.03 for storage and 0.15 for transfer would mean 3 + 15 = $18/month, assuming 100GB and each byte is downloaded once per month. Are there other costs I am not taking into account? The load balancer rules were more than $20 last I checked not taking into account storage or transfer.

Comment: The billing information in the documentation is complete.  If you observe something otherwise, reach out to Firebase support. The Stack Overflow community can't help with billing issues.